# Submit Html Form to Servlet in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

it´s weird..

i got a simple file /WebContent/login.html with an form

```
<form action="/LoginHandler" method="POST">
```

and some classes with web.xml

```
/Java Resources/src/controller/LoginHandler.java
/Java Resources/src/controller/ProtectedResource.java
```

e.g. LoginHandler.java

```
package controller;

[imports]

@WebServlet("/LoginHandler")
public class LoginHandler extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public LoginHandler() {
    super();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse ...
```

/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml defined like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<display-name>Webshop</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Webshop.controller.LoginHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProtectedResource</servlet-name>
    ...

</web-app>
```

even if i run that i get

```
http://localhost:8080/Webshop/login.html
```

but if i submit the form i get this here:

```
http://localhost:8080/servlet?user=foo&password=bar
```

with an 404 Status!

where does it come from? is there anything i dont mind of?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your web application is deployed under context root /Webshop based on login html url you give. Thus your form should be

```
<form action="/Webshop/LoginHandler" method="POST">
```

Comment: i tried that already: http://localhost:8080/Webshop/LoginHandler is the right target.. even if i use your absolute path /Wenshop/LoginHandler i´ll get http://localhost:8080/LoginHandler + 404 Error

Comment: In your comments, you have Wenshop instead of WebShop. Is that a typo in your code or is it a typo in the comment? Also in your original post, the final url that you get 404 error is http://localhost:8080/servlet?.. and here you said the url is localhost:8080/LoginHandler. Which one is true?

Comment: its typ in my comment.. sorry for that. i dont know why he is redirecting now to localhost:8080/LoginHandler.. yesterday it was localhost:8080/servlet?.. anyway my question is: is there any possibility to define a default redirect if the source is not found? my web.xml and my form are defined well or not? i dont know why the form is not send to localhost:8080/Webpage/LoginHandler even if i specify the form like this: <form action="/Webshop/LoginHandler" method="POST">

Comment: You can define <error-page><error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page> for the redirect page if the 404 happens. However, your problem is very weird. Can you hit http://localhost:8080/Webshop/LoginHandler in the browser directly?

Comment: yes directly is no problem! even if i got http://localhost:8080/Webshop/ErrorPage.html and specify the error-page in web.xml like you said i get redirected to http://localhost:8080/LoginHandler with the standard 404 error and not my custom error-page! it´s exhausted! EDIT if i rename the files with .jsp instead of .html it´s working fine after <%@page import="controller.*"%> .. maybe the tomcat dont like the .html files???

Answer (score 1):

Change your html from

from

```
<form action="/LoginHandler" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="../LoginHandler" method="POST">
```

Comment: i tried that already: http://localhost:8080/Webshop/LoginHandler is the right target.. even if i use your the root directory discriptor ../ i´ll get http://localhost:8080/LoginHandler + 404 Error